# Change the new facebook page plugin width

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

The new facebook page plugin has the minimum width at 280px (inserted by a data-width:280px).

However when I inspect the element created by the script with firebug i see an element with id="u_0_0" with the width at 280 but i can modify it from console to be as i need (227px).

I've tried to modify it with a little script made with jquery (i can only work with jquery 1.2...an old version of it...) but it doesent seams to work since the element is inserted dinamicaly into the DOM.

I also tried an method finded by google but also it doesn't work:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#u_0_0').live('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
       alert(jQuery('#u_0_0').html());
   });
});
```

The above method doesn't work and if i dont use live it alerts me with undefined...

So, how can i get the element so i can modify it's css ? Maybe jquery 1.2.1 is too old but maybe i can get and modify it with clasic javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The plugin renders in an `iframe` which is a separate `DOM` from yours.
- Because of that reason, its not possible to run scripts on the plugin from your website

In your script:

`jQuery('#u_0_0')` is not able to find the `div`, since that doesn't exist on your `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use javascript or css on an object inside a iframe.

If you look upside on code you will see the iframe.

You can do that only if the location of the iframe target is cross-domain but i'm not sure.

Comment: no, there is no iframe on the new facebook page plugin....https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: @florin: Yes, but Facebook will _create_ an iframe inside your page, that the Page plugin content is rendered into. And therefor, you can not manipulate its content with JavaScript, nor can you inject any CSS styles of your own. You need to make do with the configure options that Facebook provides for the plugin.

Comment: well, this sucks..i need with of 230px and they only let min-width of 280...so no luck for me...